Issues with JavaScript Alert in WordPress Theme (Blocksy) Development
I want to develop something on WordPress, using the Blocksy theme.
Firstly, I want to test if my HTML and JavaScript work properly by creating a simple input button.
I tested it in VScode first. When the user enters an email and clicks submit, the webpage should show an alert saying "Hello from JavaScript!"
Here's my code:
HTML (body part only):
<form>
    <label for="email">Enter Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" multiple="">
    <input type="submit" id="useremail" name="submit">
    <script src="index.js"></script>     
</form>

index.js:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("useremail").onclick = function() {
        alert("Hello from JavaScript!");
    };
});

After testing in VScode and confirming it works, I tried the same code on WordPress. However, no matter what I try, the alert message doesn't show up after clicking submit.
I've read through many articles but still haven't found a solution. Here are the steps I followed:

open edit post page.
Upload "email-script.js" to "/wp-content/themes/blocksy/static/js/", so the path is "/wp-content/themes/blocksy/static/js/email-script.js".

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    console.log("Document ready! Kuan");
    console.log("hello kuan");
    document.getElementById("useremail").onclick = function() {
        alert("Hello from JavaScript!");
    };
});


Add a custom HTML block and paste the code (changed src to my custom JavaScript path according to my blocksy path):

<form>
    <label for="email">Enter Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" multiple="">
    <input type="submit" id="useremail" name="submit">
    <script src="/wp-content/themes/blocksy/static/js/email-script.js"></script>
</form>


Added the following code to "/wp-content/themes/blocksy/functions.php":

function load_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-email-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/static/js/email-script.js', array(), false, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_scripts');

I've checked the console, there is no error. Is there anything I'm missing?

Are there any other forms in the same page? querySelector will only select the first one. To be sure of identifying the correct form it would be better to use an ID selector than a tag selector.

I tried the same code on WordPress...actually, from what you've posted, it seems you tried some different code (which is fine, but it does suffer from the difference I just pointed out - the first sample gets the element by an ID, the second one just finds the first form on the page)

@ADyson I tried so many codes in the past 3 hours. I am so sorry if I posted something wrong. Let me try it again right now.

@ADyson something weird just happened. I only have a file called "email-script.js", but right now in check - Sources I have two files called "email-script.js" and "email-script.js?ver=6.4.4". I reuploaded my email-script.js from WinSCP, the code is still the same, not changing at all.

Have you tried doing a hard reload of your whole page - i.e. Ctrl+F5 ? this will force the browser to update all resources, such as JS files, from the server rather than loading from its cache (which it will often do by default for JS and CSS files)

@ADyson Thank you for your comments. I finally made it!

After hours, I finally made it!
The problem is from HTML.
Here is the correct solution for my case.
<form>
    <label for="emailInput">Enter Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" autocomplete="email" multiple="">
    <input type="submit" id="useremail" name="submit">
<script src="/wp-content/themes/blocksy/static/js/email-script.js"></script>
</form>

The "for" in label should point to an exist id. For example, initially it pointed to a id that doesn't exist. After I made it point to "emailInput". The error vanished.  Now is working fine!
